# Media queries not working to display nav on Desktop

Tags: css, responsive-design

I've put into my page media queries so when you view on a mobile device you get the responsive 'burger' menu  to see the navigation.

The responsive menu seems to be working ok but I've ended up getting lost and confused within my CSS as to how to get the responsive menu only show on a mobile as it shows on desktop too.

The navigation has a class set to nav-collapse. [Here's the live URL](http://www.directiongroup.com/retail/retail-services.html) that I'll temporarily post, but the CSS used is below:-

```
.nav-collapse,
.nav-collapse ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 550px;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px 20px 0 0;
}

.nav-collapse li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-collapse a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f7d223;
  font-family: 'DINLightRegular', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0.7em 1em;
  float: left;
}


.nav-collapse ul ul a {
  background: #ca3716;
  padding-left: 2em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .nav-collapse li {
    width: 25%;
    *width: 24.9%; /* IE7 Hack */
    _width: 19%; /* IE6 Hack */
  }
  .nav-collapse,
.nav-collapse ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 530px;
  margin: 16px 10px 0 10px;
}
.nav-collapse a {
margin: 0;
padding: 1em;
float: left;
text-align: center;
border-bottom: 0;
  }
      .nav-collapse ul ul a {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .nav-collapse,
.nav-collapse ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 340px;
  margin: 16px 10px 0 10px;
}
}
```

How do I show burger menu only on mobile and standard navigation on desktop in this CSS?

Comment: If you don't want to show it on desktop then just hide it normally and make it display block on mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Huangism states, the most common method to achieve this is to hide by default for desktop/tablet with the rule `display: none`.

Then when your media query is active for a specific size, change to `display:block` or inline, inline-block, etc as your situation warrants.

It is not clear what he nav-collapse rules are intending to accomplish. There are conflicts present in the rules displayed.

A simple change of the `display:` rule will show/hide as needed.